# Convert 1D (numpy) array whose components are 1D arrays to a 2D array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

The question is admittedly not worded too greatly, but I'll try to explain better here. I essentially have a numpy array whose shape is `(10800, )`. Each component of this array is another numpy array whose shape is `(512, )`. It looks something like this:

```
[array([1, 2, 3])
 array([4, 5, 6])]
```

Where here, this has shape `(2, )` and every line has shape `(3, )`. Note that there are no commas between the two arrays.

So, back to the initial array, I would like to convert it into a numpy array of shape `(10800, 512)`. Thank you!

Comment: did you try `np.array(your_array)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Hi, I don't have any list. Maybe I misunderstood your point?

Comment: I mean `array`. Would be interesting how you got your initial array in the first place.

Comment: @QuangHoang Just tried it. Didn't work :/ The way I got it in the first place is messy. I initially got a csv file whose rows were supposed to be lists of numbers, but instead every row was a single string in which the numbers were packed together and separated by ";". So, I converted every row from a string to a numpy array. I know there must be more efficient ways to do it, but I'm a noob for now :d

Comment: Sounds like a Pandas thing. Anyway, things would be easier if you convert every row to a list instead of numpy array. AFAIK, `np.array(...)` doesn't work only if the sub-arrays don't have the same length (or possibly different dtype).

Comment: @QuangHoang I did it, and then I have an array of shape (10800, ) in which every component is a list. I just tried to do the no.array(my_array) thing, but every component is still a list for some reason.

Comment: What's the `dtype` of this array?  Look at a sample element.  Is it an array of numbers?  Or is it string(s)?   You could try `np.array(data, dtype=int)`, or `np.stack(data)`.

Comment: Check all the length again with `set([len(x) for x in your_big_array])`.

Comment: @hpaulj the dtype of the big array is object. The dtype of each individual row is float64. This is strange

Comment: Most likely some of those component arrays have a different length.

Comment: @hpaulj np.stack worked brilliantly! I now have a numpy array of (10800 , 512). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you too!

Comment: @TheQuantumMan if you are using `csv.reader` you can specify `delimiter = ';'` when opening the csv file

Comment: @MaxwellRedacted I'm using pandas. Specifically, I tried using `pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';', engine='python')`. This doesn't seem to work though. It produces the error `pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 3 fields in line 4, saw 4`. Is there an alternative method to use?

Comment: Does line 4 have four values instead of 3, pandas will determine the number of columns from the first line, so if your first line has 3 values, thats how many columns it will think there is

Comment: @MaxwellRedacted The thing is that the first line has as many values as any other line (I checked by manually opening the csv file). So, I have no clue as to what might be going on here. This is just data from a lab, so the first line's format should (and seems to be) identical to any other line.

Comment: weird, I have used this before although I haven't a measured how efficient it is: `with open('groundtruth.csv', 'r') as gtf: gt_label = np.array([x.split(';') for x in gtf.read().splitlines()], dtype = np.float32)`

Comment: @MaxwellRedacted It turns out that it reads only the four last numbers of the first line, for some reason. It ignores the rest. Strange. Will try your other method soon, if you don't have any ideas on how this pronlem shows up in the first place

Comment: @TheQuantumMan very weird, difficult to suggest anything else without the actual file, if you are happy with the solution you currently have, I wouldn't worry much more, it is outside the scope of your original question anyway, unless you want to ask a new question and attach the file using one of the methods from here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47689/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-a-post

Comment: @MaxwellRedacted Thanks a lot for the help. I did find a way around it. I just read the problematic line by itself and manually converted the string to numbers and then added the resulting two arrays. I think it doesn't cost too much to do it this way, as I'm only isolating a single line.